Prevent Unattended Upgrades from restarting service
Is it possible to prevent unattended-upgrades from restarting specific services?
A critical systemd service in production sometimes is restarted when a dependency is upgraded by unattended-upgrades which causes data-loss, what is the correct way to disable service restarts?

If you are running such essential services, please turn off unattended upgrades altogether. What if there is a faulty upgrade that breaks your production line? Instead, manually upgrade at regular intervals when you have a backup system around

Rather than haywire Unattended Upgrades, stop using that service in production systems. Use your maintenance windows for their intended purpose.
Edit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
Change the following line to "0"
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";   <--- Change to "0" to disable

